# Add multiple images to multiple bodies

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I have the following code and it puts an image to 1 random body.

```
for (var b:b2Body=world.GetBodyList(); b; b=b.GetNext()) {
    for (var i:int=0; i<3; i++) {
        var distX:Number = b.GetPosition().x * worldScale - (220 + i * 100);
        var distY:Number = b.GetPosition().y * worldScale - 180;

        if (b.GetType()==b2Body.b2_dynamicBody) {
            myBlock.x = distX + (220 + i * 100);
            myBlock.y = distY + 180;
            myBlock.rotation = b.GetAngle() * 180 / Math.PI;
            //world.DestroyBody(b);
            //createBox(220 + i * 100,180,b2Body.b2_staticBody);
        }       
    }
}
```

I want to be able to add multiple images to multiple bodies. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but I can give you a great website. I was learning box2d with it and its very useful

[here it is](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/category/box2d/)